# how can i combine fitness and diabets together ? how can i be a professioal athlete?

Tags: injury, health, food, football

Doctor's said that you cant exercise anymore , now i see nacho ( REAL MADRID F.C midfielder ) can play football as well as anyoe else , in high rate and grade , although he has diabets since he was 12 !
i'll be happy if you help me .

Comment: There are many athletes at all levels that perform quite well with diabetes. This is something you should work out with your doctors and coaches.

Answer (score 2):

Reason why doctor don't want you to train is that while exercising sugar level in your blood can vary. Too low level can be dangerous for you. There are diabetics who do train, but that requires extra care. Since your life is in stake no one will guide you over Internet. Find out people in your country who train, and ask them for contacts to doctors, more help. Please note that doctors are humans as we all. Some of them are better skilled, some are more deliberative. Find one that can help you, but please be care, and do not do it for your own. That is really serious.